# Do you know of any ways to effectively manage a triple screen setup brightness?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, brightness

1. I use a desktop with multiple monitors
2. I have tried [F.lux](http://www.stereopsis.com/flux/) and it is a great app for changing the color from 3500k-6500k... but doesn't adjust screen brightness. (I recommend you try it)

I've googled for hours trying to find an app that will work to let me easily manage screen brightness either by a "dim when idle" or a dynamically updating screen brightness based on the time of day.  Windows 7 desktop doesn't seem to have options for me to adjust brightness on the system, and manually changing three separate monitors is too much of a chore?

Anybody have some recommendations? Perhaps a way to script this, knowledge of how to use the [supposed dynamic screen brightness functions](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/system/pnppwr/powermgmt/BrightnessCtrl.mspx) that Windows was supposed to add in Windows 7?

Comment: Use the buttons on the monitors?

Comment: .... quote: " and manually changing three separate monitors is too much of a chore?"   Doing that daily would not be fun. :-)

Answer (score 0):

"There are several tools available for monitor calibration, one that is readily available for download is PowerStrip. The advantage of a tool like this is that you can adjust all monitors from a single location, and you can create different monitor profiles, for example a brighter one for use at day, and a second for use at night.", source: [Multi-monitor FAQ](http://www.realtimesoft.com/multimon/faq.asp)

Comment: http://entechtaiwan.com/util/ps.shtm
I agree it fits some of the specs. I had already reviewed it. I should have specified freeware/open source though. I have a problem paying $29.95 to change my monitor brightness :-)

Comment: i guess i'm more asking what could automatically reduce brightness, gamma, and contrast to 0..... that would be great!